# Performance-wise, is it better to query a relationship field or a formula field?

Tags: soql, formula, query, relationships, performance

Like `AccountName` vs `Account.Name`. The first being a formula field, and the second one a relationship.

Since formula fields are like Schrödinger's Cat (the value depends on the time you are getting its value), I suppose there is a query on the background. My doubt is whether it is faster than a direct relationship query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the formula is literally:

```
Account.Name
```

Then you get the use of indexes, such that:

```
WHERE AccountName__c = 'Demo'
WHERE Account.Name = 'Demo'
```

Are identical in performance.

[image: Formula Using Index]

If you use any sort of formula function, it reverts to a TableScan, resulting in a massive performance drop:

```
BLANKVALUE(Account.Name, '--None--')
```

[image: Formula Not Using Index]

In the first formula, your users will not likely experience timeouts from queries being too complicated (e.g. non-selective query errors), but in the latter, your users may experience performance problems (longer query execution time and/or non-selective query errors).

Comment: Is it good practice to use formulas instead of querying relationship field.

Lets say in Trigger,  if I want to refer parentAccount's name on the Account I am working on, if I just use formula i will save SOQL.. as I have an unlimited license so having 800 fields and creating formula fields helps me save a bunch of queries.  If formulas are simple it wont have any performance implications?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal There's a trade off to using formulas this way, and it's nothing to do with performance. When you create formulas just to pull in data from a related record, it makes code maintenance more challenging. I would recommend doing this only as a last resort (e.g. you're already at the governor limit) and document it clearly. There's nothing more frustrating than having to look in Setup while reading code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult to provide a blanket answer, but there are some techniques you can use to write more efficient queries. There is a good [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/database_basics_dotnet/units/writing_efficient_queries) detailing such practices.

Additionally, Salesforce provides a great tool via their dev tool called [Query Plan](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1) which allows you to compare the actual "cost" of queries against each other.